# React form loses focus on update

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, react-state, rerender, react-effects

I am working on a form that has, among other fields, calendar entries - dates and times. The code is below:

```
  {dates.map((d, i) => (
      <div className="date-time-entry" key={i}>
        <div className="date-picker">
          <DatePicker
            selected={new Date(d.startDate)}
            dateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
            onChange={date => {
              const newDates = [...dates]
              newDates[i].startDate = date
              setDates(newDates)
            }}
          />
          to
          <DatePicker
            selected={new Date(d.endDate)}
            dateFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
            onChange={date => {
              const newDates = [...dates]
              newDates[i].endDate = date
              setDates(newDates)
            }}
          />
          {i ? (
            <span
              onClick={() => {
                const newDates = dates.filter((d, k) => k !== i)
                setDates(newDates)
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
            </span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
        {dates[i].times.map((t, j) => {
          return (
            <div className="time-picker" key={j}>
              at
              <input
                ref={(input) => { nameInput = input }}
                value={t.start}
                onChange={e => {
                  const newDates = [...dates]
                  newDates[i].times[j].start = e.target.value
                  setDates(newDates)
                }}
              />{' '}
              to{' '}
              <input
                ref={(input) => { nameInput = input }}
                value={t.end}
                onChange={e => {
                  const newDates = [...dates]
                  newDates[i].times[j].end = e.target.value
                  setDates(newDates)
                }}
              />
              <span
                onClick={() => {
                  const newTimes = dates[i].times.filter((t, k) => k !== j)
                  const newDates = [...dates]
                  newDates[i].times = newTimes
                  setDates(newDates)
                }}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
              </span>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <div
          className="add-time"
          onClick={() => {
            const newDates = [...dates]
            newDates[i].times = [
              ...newDates[i].times,
              { start: '12:00', end: '13:00' }
            ]
            setDates(newDates)
          }}
        >
          Add Time
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  )}
```

Then there is the `useState()` hook defined as:

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([
  {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    times: [{ start: '12:00', end: '13:00' }]
  }
])
```

The problem that I am having is that whenever onChange is called - each keystroke the rerender occurs and my component loses focus.

I tried using `onBlur` and `defaultValue` instead of `onChange`, but there is also a focus problem - two clicks are needed for the focus to switch because the first one is consumed by rerendering.

I also tried adding timeout to deal with `onBlur` "losing" one click as below:

```
<input
  defaultValue={t.start}
  onBlur={e => {
    const value = e.target.value
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      const newDates = [...dates]
      newDates[i].times[j].start = value
      setDates(newDates)
    }, 0)
  }}
  onFocus={() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }}
/>
```

The last version does not lose focus anymore, yet instead, it loses state updates. Any suggestions as to how better handle this, or maybe even fix my existing code?

Comment: This is just a hint, but I'm pretty sure the problem is coming from a changing key. When the key changes, the component, instead of being updated on the same instance, is unmounted and a new instance is mounted. This also involves DOM objects, which will clear focus. So this may not be the answer, but it's a common cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good idea to have the following code:

```
{dates[i].times.map((t, j) => {
      return (
        <div className="time-picker" key{j}>
          at
          <input
            ref={(input) => { nameInput = input }}
            value={t.start}
            onChange={e => {
              const newDates = [...dates]
              newDates[i].times[j].start = e.target.value
              setDates(newDates)
            }}
          />{' '}
          to{' '}
          <input
            ref={(input) => { nameInput = input }}
            value={t.end}
            onChange={e => {
              const newDates = [...dates]
              newDates[i].times[j].end = e.target.value
              setDates(newDates)
            }}
          />
          <span
            onClick={() => {
              const newTimes = dates[i].times.filter((t, k) => k !== j)
              const newDates = [...dates]
              newDates[i].times = newTimes
              setDates(newDates)
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    })}
```

Each time, any change in dates, it will re-render all components again.
You should have every time picker as a separate component like the following:

```
const changeHandler = (i, j, x, val) => {
  const newDates = [...dates]
  newDates[i].times[j][x] = val
  setDates(newDates)
}
const clickHandler = (i, j) => {
  const newTimes = dates[i].times.filter((t, k) => k !== j)
  const newDates = [...dates]
  newDates[i].times = newTimes
  setDates(newDates)
}
{dates[i].times.map((t, j) => {
  return (
    <MyTimePicker time={t} k={"time_" + j} changeHandler={( val,  x="start" ) => changeHandler(i, j, x, val)} clickHandler={() => clickHandler(i, j)}>
  )
 })}
```

and in another file "my-timepicker.js", you should define your component:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if(JSON.stringify(prevProps.time) == JSON.stringify(nextProps.time)) return true;
  return false;
}
const MyTimePicker = React.memo(({changeHandler, clickHandler, time }) => {
   const atInputRef = useRef();
   const toInputRef = useRef();
   return ( 
     <div className="time-picker">
       at
       <input
          ref={atRef}
          value={time.start}
          onChange={e => {
            changeHandler(e.target.value)
          }}
       />{' '}
       to{' '}
       <input
         ref={toRef}
         value={time.end}
         onChange={e => {
           changeHandler(e.target.value, "end")
         }}
       />
       <span
         onClick={clickHandler}
       >
         <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
       </span>
     </div>
   )
}, areEqual);
```

Comment: Tried your code. Think that your `nameInput` is maybe undefined. Don't see any difference in the behaviour.

Comment: @IgorShmukler I have edited the answer to fix nameInput and also I used React.memo to make sure that the component doesn't rerender if time value doesn't change

Comment: Now, it works exactly like the original version - loses focus.

Comment: @IgorShmukler Also, I noticed a mistake in the code. Your `keys` should have a prefix. 
I added `time` prefix for the time array and at the top of your code, you should change the dates to the following: 
`{dates.map((d, i) => (
      <div className="date-time-entry" key={"date_" + i}>`

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. Did you try running your own code? Thank you.